# Timezone setting for neo4j.log

Tags: neo4j

The timestamps in my neo4j.log file are 10 hours off from what the unix date command returns.  I don't see a parameter in neo4j.conf for timezone.  Is there anyway to get configure the time zone for timestamps in neo4j.log???

Answer (score 4):

> From the 3.3.1 version it is possible to configure the timezone. Just add the following to your neo4j.conf -

```
# possible values - [UTC, SYSTEM]
dbms.logs.timezone=SYSTEM
```

> Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The timestamps in the Neo4j logs are in UTC. This is not configurable.

Comment: Link to the offical note for reference: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-do-i-convert-neo4j-logs-from-base-utc-to-local-timezone/

Answer (score 0):

For Neo4j 4.x and later:
The timestamps in logs are in UTC by default.
This can be overridden to SYSTEM timezone using dbms.db.timezone

1. Edit neo4j.conf
2. Add `dbms.db.timezone=SYSTEM` to the file as a new line
3. Save changes
4. Restart the server

Reference: [dbms.db.timezone](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/5/configuration/configuration-settings/#config_dbms.db.timezone)